# Create Image_3 instance by passing height, width, depth and data pointer in CGAL

Tags: c++, image, cgal

CGAL provides a method to instance a Image_3 object by function `read`, that is reading an existing image file from disk. I'm wondering whether I can instance it with `height,width,depth` and a `data pointer` like this:

```
CGAL::Image_3 im;
int Height = 512;
int Width = 512;
int Depth = 100;
int* dataptr = new int [Height*Width*Depth];
memset(dataptr, 0, sizeof(int)*Height*Width*Depth);
MyCreate(im, Height, Width, Depth, dataptr); // <== my function to instance this object.
```

So how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following non-documented piece of code (not really tested):

```
// create and fill the _image struct
_image* image = ::_initImage();
image->vectMode = VM_SCALAR;
image->xdim = Height;
image->ydim = Width
image->zdim = Depth;
image->vdim = 1;
image->vx = 1.;
image->vy = 1.;
image->vz = 1.;
image->endianness = ::_getEndianness();
image->wdim = sizeof(int);
image->wordKind = WK_FIXED;
image->sign = SGN_SIGNED;
image->data = dataptr;

// then create the CGAL::Image_3 object:
CGAL::Image_3 im(image);
```

I have adapted the code from the function `Image_3::read_vtk_image_data` (in `CGAL-4.5/src/CGAL_ImageIO/Image_3.cpp`.